# How I add larger size of image in IconButton on flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

In IconButton has "icon:_isRecording " boolean and I added an image and I gave the size of the image as 50 but then show me this error.

[image]

I choose IconButton for this in the IconButton we can pass the boolean value as I did. I tried to pass in a column widget but that didn't work. So I used IconButton. How to resolve it?
my code.

```
   IconButton(
              icon: _isRecording
                  ? Column(
                      children: const [
                        Icon(
                          Icons.pause,
                          size: 30,
                        ),
                        LinearProgressIndicator(
                            semanticsLabel: 'Linear progress indicator'),
                      ],
                    )
                  : Column(
                      children: const [
                        ImageIcon(
                          AssetImage("assets/mic2.png"),
                          size: 50,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
              onPressed: _onRecordButtonPressed,
            ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `iconSize` from `IconButton`, default value is 24

```dart
IconButton(
  iconSize: x,// based on your need
  ),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your IconButton with a SizedBox